# How to set a JSON object from local.storage using setState with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, react-hooks, use-state

Consider the following—I have a conditional which checks `local storage` for a `JSON object` and if it doesn't exist it set its in local storage:

It's being set correctly:

[image]

**BUT** if it does exist I'd like to get it from local storage and set it to my state with `useState`:

```
export default function Day({ dayInfo }) {


var [dayInfoInChild, setDayInfoInChild] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dayInfo !== null) {
      var modifiedDayInfo = dayInfo
        .split(' ')
        .map((item) => {
          if (item.indexOf(',')) return item.replace(/,/g, '');
        })
        .join('-');

      if (localStorage.getItem(modifiedDayInfo)) {
        setDayInfoInChild((dayInfoInChild) => [
          ...dayInfoInChild,
          modifiedDayInfo,
        ]);
        console.log('dayInfoInChild', dayInfoInChild);
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem(modifiedDayInfo, JSON.stringify({}));
      }
    }
  }, [dayInfo]);
```

The log returns:

```
`dayInfoInChild` ["April-2-2020", "April-3-2020"]
```

I'd like it to be:

```
`dayInfoInChild` ["April-2-2020" : "{}", "April-3-2020": "{}"]`
```

How is this achieved? Black magic welcomed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you push to the state only `modifiedDayInfo`.

You have to take also the value from local storage:

I didn't test it, but it's supposed to be something like that

```
 setDayInfoInChild((dayInfoInChild) => [
              ...dayInfoInChild,
              {[modifiedDayInfo],JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("April-2"))},
            ]);
```

In code:

```
export default function Day({ dayInfo }) {


var [dayInfoInChild, setDayInfoInChild] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dayInfo !== null) {
      var modifiedDayInfo = dayInfo
        .split(' ')
        .map((item) => {
          if (item.indexOf(',')) return item.replace(/,/g, '');
        })
        .join('-');

      if (localStorage.getItem(modifiedDayInfo)) {
        setDayInfoInChild((dayInfoInChild) => [
          ...dayInfoInChild,
          {[modifiedDayInfo],JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("April-2"))
         },
        ]);
        console.log('dayInfoInChild', dayInfoInChild);
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem(modifiedDayInfo, JSON.stringify({}));
      }
    }
  }, [dayInfo]);
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks Esther that worked, but would you say my state in my component should be `{}` i.e. JavasScript object instead of an array `[]`, because that way semantically, I can mirror the `local-storage` e.g. `var localStorage = { key : value}` and later `localStorage = { april-2: {...data about april 2}}`